# Gitosis Directories of repositories per user?

Tags: git, gitosis, repository

I was just wondering, is there a way to set up gitosis so that a user would have their own directory to which they could push any number of repositories that they want, and essentially have admin privs on that directory? This might be kind of confusing, but essentially I want something like how on github all your repositories are accessible at urls like git@github.com:username/repofoo.git .

I realize that setting up each repo is a somewhat manual process that could be automated via a script, like I assume github does, but is there any way to do something like this overall, minus the automated repository creation? I guess I'm open to trying to set up gitorious or something if it allows this, but gitosis works pretty well for me right now and it was dead easy to set up, and I've heard that gitorious is not so easy. Thanks!

I've heard of other forks/clones of gitosis that have per branch permissions like gitolite, but I'm not sure whether I want to use one of those unless they have other compelling features and are as well documented and easy to use as gitosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite what I was looking for, and I don't think gitosis can do it without some serious scripting, but [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) apparently has a way to have permissions for personal branches. I actually might switch to it because it seems to have some other fairly compelling features.